# How do I create static C strings?

Tags: string, static, rust, ffi

I want to create a plugin module (shared lib) in Rust that exports a C compatible structure containing static C strings. In Sept 2014, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880043/creating-a-static-c-struct-containing-strings) determined it wasn't possible. As of Jan 2015 this still was not possible as per [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2tzkro/compiletime_static_c_strings/). Has anything changed since?

Comment: I would hope that [RFC 911](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0911-const-fn.md) would help with this - it would allow calling `as_ptr` in a static context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to do the trick.  I don't really want the struct to be mutable, but I get core::marker::Sync errors if I don't mark it as mut.

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::funcs::c95::stdio::puts;
use std::mem;

pub struct Mystruct {
    s1: *const u8,
    s2: *const u8,
}

const CONST_C_STR: *const u8 = b"a constant c string\0" as *const u8;

#[no_mangle]
pub static mut mystaticstruct: Mystruct = Mystruct {
    s1: CONST_C_STR,
    s2: b"another constant c string\0" as *const u8
};

fn main() {
    unsafe{
        puts(mystaticstruct.s1 as *const i8); // puts likes i8
        puts(mystaticstruct.s2 as *const i8);
        println!("Mystruct size {}", mem::size_of_val(&mystaticstruct));
    }
}
```

The output (on 64 bit linux) is ...

```
a constant c string
another constant c string
Mystruct size 16
```