# How do I expose a compile time generated static C string through FFI?

Tags: rust, ffi

I am trying to embed a version number into a library. Ideally, this should be a static C string that can be read and doesn't need any additional allocation for reading the version number.

On the Rust side, I am using `vergen` to generate the versioning information like this:

```
pub static VERSION: &str = env!("VERGEN_SEMVER");
```

and I would like to end up with something like

```
#[no_mangle]
pub static VERSION_C: *const u8 = ... ;
```

There seems to be a way to achieve this using [string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563785/how-do-i-create-static-c-strings), but I haven't found a way to do this with compile time strings. Creating a new `CString` seems to be beyond the current capabilities of static variables and tends to end with an [error E0015](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/error-index.html#E0015).

A function returning the pointer like this would be acceptable, as long as it does not allocate new memory.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_version() -> *const u8 {
    // ...
}
```

The final type of the variable (or return type of the function) doesn't have to be based on `u8`, but should be translatable through `cbindgen`. If some other FFI type is more appropriate, using that is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By ensuring that the static string slice is compatible with a C-style string (as in, it ends with the null terminator byte `\0`), we can safely fetch a pointer to the beginning of the slice and pass that across the boundary.

```
pub static VERSION: &str = concat!(env!("VERGEN_SEMVER"), "\0");

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_version() -> *const c_char {
    VER.as_ptr() as *const c_char
}
```

Here's an example in the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=28d9b5e2145d033c241559f483c12843), where I used the package's version as the environment variable to fetch and called the function in Rust.

Answer (score 1):

Now, with [constant evaluation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html#constant-evaluation), you can wrap this up a little more nicely.

```rust
// SAFETY: the input must not have interior NUL bytes
macro_rules! static_cstr {
    ($l:expr) => {
        ::std::ffi::CStr::from_bytes_with_nul_unchecked(
            concat!($l, "\0").as_bytes()
        )
    }
}

pub static VERSION: &CStr = unsafe { static_cstr!(env!("VERGEN_SEMVER")) };
```

EDIT:

Inspired the discussion in the comments, we can make this safe by adding our own compile-time checks for input validity (there is an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/101719) to stabilize `const` versions of the `CStr` methods, at which point we won't need to do this ourselves):

```rust
const fn from_bytes_with_nul(b: &[u8]) -> &CStr {
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < b.len() - 1 {
        if b[i] == b'\0' {
            panic!("interior nul byte");
        }
        i += 1;
    }

    if b[b.len() - 1] != b'\0' {
        panic!("no nul-terminator");
    }

    // SAFETY: we verify above that `b` is nul-terminated
    // and has no interior nul bytes
    unsafe { CStr::from_bytes_with_nul_unchecked(b) }
}

macro_rules! static_cstr {
    ($l:expr) => { from_bytes_with_nul(concat!($l, "\0").as_bytes()) }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is technically unsound, due to `$l` possible containing inner nulls. (In practice, this is **currently** checked when calling in a const context, but this isn't guaranteed by the function, and your macro can be used in non-const contexts). See [this answer's replies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75064432/6655004), which use a similar macro, for more info.

Comment: Also, you have a `&CStr`, when a `*const u8` or `fn() -> *const u8` is requested. These are different types since `&CStr` is a fat pointer, which keeps track of the length

Comment: I have edited my response accordingly. I am surprised that it is not safe for the input to have interior NUL bytes as I would expect the resulting `CStr` to simply be the corresponding truncation. As to your latter point, the intention is that the user call `.as_ptr()` as in Shepmaster's answer. This way, however, it is encoded in the type system that their string is a valid `CStr`. Seen another way, assumption that make it is a valid `CStr` is explicit and located where the string is declared.

Comment: That's fair, OP could always just define a `fn get_version() -> *const u8` that simply calls `.as_ptr()` on `VERSION`.