# static struct with C strings for lv2 plugin

Tags: audio, static, rust

I'm trying to learn Rust (newbie in low level programming), and want to translate a tiny lv2 amplifier (audio) plugin "amp.c" ([C-code](http://lv2plug.in/git/cgit.cgi/lv2.git/tree/plugins/eg-amp.lv2/amp.c)) from C to Rust. I actually got it working ([here](https://github.com/poidl/eg-amp_rust/blob/master/src/lib.rs)), but when the host terminates, valgrind says that "
64 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost". I think I know why this happens, but I don't know how to fix it.

Before you get tired of reading, here is the final question:

How do I statically allocate a struct that contains a C string?

And here is the introduction:

**Why it happens (I think):**
Host loads the library and calls lv2_descriptor()

```
const LV2_Descriptor*
lv2_descriptor()
{
    return &descriptor;
}
```

which returns a pointer to a STATICALLY allocated struct of type LV2_Descriptor,

```
static const LV2_Descriptor descriptor = {
    AMP_URI,
    ...
};
```

which is defined as

```
typedef struct _LV2_Descriptor {
    const char * URI;
    ...
} LV2_Descriptor;
```

Why is it statically allocated? In the amp.c it says:

> It is best to define descriptors statically to avoid leaking memory
>   and non-portable shared library constructors and destructors to clean
>   up properly.

However, I translated lv2_descriptor() to Rust as:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn lv2_descriptor(index:i32) -> *const LV2Descriptor {
     let s = "http://example.org/eg-amp_rust";
     let cstr = CString::new(s).unwrap();
     let ptr = cstr.as_ptr();
     mem::forget(cstr);

     let mybox = Box::new(LV2Descriptor{amp_uri: ptr}, ...);
     let bxptr = &*mybox as *const LV2Descriptor; 
     mem::forget(mybox);
     return  bxptr
     }
```

So it's not statically allocated and I never free it, that's I guess why valgrind complains?

**How am I trying to solve it?**
I'm trying to do the same thing in Rust as the C-code does, i.e. statically allocate the struct (*outside* of lv2_descriptor()). The goal is to be fully compatible to the lv2 library, i.e "...to avoid leaking memory..." etc., as it says in the quote, right? So I tried something like:

```
static ptr1: *const u8 = (b"example.org/eg-amp_rust\n\0").as_ptr();
static ptr2: *const libc::c_char = ptr1 as *const libc::c_char;
static desc: LV2Descriptor = LV2Descriptor{amp_uri: ptr2, ...};
```

But this does not compile, there are error messages like

```
src/lib.rs:184:26: 184:72 error: the trait `core::marker::Sync` is not implemented for the type `*const u8` [E0277]
src/lib.rs:184 static ptr1: *const u8 = b"http://example.org/eg-amp_rust\n\0".as_ptr();
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:184:26: 184:72 note: `*const u8` cannot be shared between threads safely
src/lib.rs:184 static ptr1: *const u8 = b"http://example.org/eg-amp_rust\n\0".as_ptr();
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:184:26: 184:72 error: static contains unimplemented expression type [E0019]
src/lib.rs:184 static ptr1: *const u8 = b"http://example.org/eg-amp_rust\n\0".as_ptr();
```

**Specific problem/question:**

How do I statically allocate a struct that contains a C string?

Comment: A *newbie in low level programming* who uses valgrind, understands its report and tracked down the memory leak? I tip my hat to you sir!

Comment: @Shepmaster: Thanks, I didn't see that, it is indeed the same problem. I tried ker's answer and it works perfectly, so maybe we can adapt ker's answer to the original question and delete this one?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Well, I had to write a ~1000 line Fortran program once for work, and had to use valgrind there...I guess compared to most people here I'm still quite a newbie:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, you don't for now. Future Rust will probably gain this ability.

What you can do, is statically allocate a struct that contains null pointers, and set those null pointers to something useful when you call the function. Rust has `static mut`. It requires **unsafe code**, is **not threadsafe** at all and is (to the best of my knowledge) considered a **code smell**.

Right here I consider it a workaround to the fact that there is no way to turn a `&[T]` into a `*const T` in a static.

```
static S: &'static [u8] = b"http://example.org/eg-amp_rust\n\0";
static mut desc: LV2Descriptor = LV2Descriptor {
    amp_uri: 0 as *const libc::c_char, // ptr::null() isn't const fn (yet)
};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn lv2_descriptor(index: i32) -> *const LV2Descriptor {
     let ptr = S.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_char;
     unsafe {
        desc.amp_uri = ptr;
        &desc as *const LV2Descriptor
     }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I tried and the valgrind message disappeared. Thanks! I should point out for people interested in lv2, that there must be *no* newline '\n' in the amp_uri string. My mistake.