# How does one design a plugin interface for digital-audio-workstation hosts in pure Rust?

Tags: plugins, rust, ffi, lv2

I'm a beginner writing an LV2 audio plugin in Rust, and as a "side effect" I wrote an [LV2 interface in Rust](https://github.com/poidl/lv2). A GitHub user noted that

> this is a raw C API that you can only use in unsafe. A good library needs a rustic api with traits and types.

and I have questions on how to do that.

**EDIT** The question was addressed by Shepmaster's comment below. Although the comment doesn't answer the question directly, it makes the question much less relevant to me at the moment. I wrongly assumed that *all* Rust libraries should provide an idiomatic Rust interface.

Consider a very simple [amplifier plugin in C](http://lv2plug.in/book/#_amp_c), which I translated to Rust like so:

```
extern crate libc;
extern crate lv2;
use std::ptr;

// This is a simple "amplifier" plugin. It holds references to input and output
// buffers, and a reference to a single number (gain) by which the input buffer
// is multiplied. Memory managemet of these resources is done by the host.

pub struct AmpNew<'a> {
    gain: &'a f32,
    input: &'a [f32],
    output: &'a mut [f32],
}

// The main question is: Should one use raw pointers instead of references in this
// struct?

// I'd say NO, because:

// I want to implement "lv2::LV2HandleNew"
// without having to use "unsafe", i.e. to "provide a safe interface" to the
// lv2 library. What is the correct (let's say idiomatic) way to "provide a safe
// interface"?

// I'd say YES, because:

// *) AFAIK it's impossible to implement a constructor "::new()" function for this
// struct, since the resources go out of scope when "new()" terminates. Instead, the
// plugin is instantiated by the lv2::instantiate::<>() function using
// libc::malloc(), similar to the code I commented at the bottom of this page.
// It seems weired to not being able to allocate the plugin from safe code.
// How would one design a plugin interface in pure Rust (i.e.
// with a host written in Rust)?

// *) There are potential problems arising with unkown buffer sizes. The function
// connect_port() below takes an "&'a mut [f32]", which is constructed in the
// calling function (containing unsafe code) by "slice::from_raw_parts_mut()",
// which needs a buffer size as argument. This size is not passed by host to
// the extern "C" connect_port(). Instead,
// the host passes the "n_samples" argument to the real-time "run()" function to
// indicate which part of the buffer it wants to have processed by the plugin.
// This may not be an issue, since one can pass a really high buffer size
// to "slice::from_raw_parts_mut()" without having to worry about perfomance/space,
// since no resources are actually allocated anyways, right?

impl<'a> lv2::LV2HandleNew<'a> for AmpNew<'a> {
    // For now, initialize() is a placeholder function that doesn't do anything. More complicated plugins may scan host features, set a sample rate, etc.
    fn initialize(&mut self) {}
    fn connect_port(&mut self, port: u32, data: &'a mut [f32]) {
        match port {
            0 => self.gain = &data[0] as &f32, // data may be NULL pointer, so don't dereference!
            1 => self.input = data as &'a [f32],
            2 => self.output = data,
            _ => panic!("Not a valid PortIndex: {}", port),
        }
    }
    fn activate(&mut self) {}
    fn run(&mut self, n_samples: u32) {

        let coef: f32;
        match *self.gain > -90.0 {
            true => coef = (10.0 as f32).powf(self.gain * 0.05),
            false => coef = 0.0,
        }
        for x in 0..n_samples {
            let i = x as usize;
            self.output[i] = self.input[i] * coef;
        }

    }
    fn deactivate(&mut self) {}
    fn cleanup(&mut self) {}
}

type Newtype<'a> = AmpNew<'a>;

// If I understand correctly, the lv2::LV2Descriptor struct that is delivered
// to the host by "lv2_descriptor()" CANNOT be generic over "Newtype", since this
// would require "lv2_descriptor()" to be generic. But functions called from C
// (by their name) CANNOT be generic.
// The reason why "lv2::instantiate::<>" etc. CAN be generic, is that those functions
// get passed to C via FUNCTION POINTERS contained in a #[repr(C)] struct.
// A secondary question is: Is this necessary? How to implement this more
// effectively?

static S: &'static [u8] = b"http://example.org/eg-amp_rust\0";
static mut desc: lv2::LV2Descriptor = lv2::LV2Descriptor {
    uri: 0 as *const libc::c_char, // ptr::null() isn't const fn (yet)
    instantiate: lv2::instantiate::<Newtype>,
    connect_port: lv2::connect_port::<Newtype>,
    activate: lv2::activate,
    run: lv2::run::<Newtype>,
    deactivate: lv2::deactivate,
    cleanup: lv2::cleanup,
    extension_data: lv2::extension_data,
};


#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn lv2_descriptor(index: i32) -> *const lv2::LV2Descriptor {
    if index != 0 {
        return ptr::null();
    } else {
        // credits to ker on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334356/static-struct-with-c-strings-for-lv2-plugin (duplicate) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880043/creating-a-static-c-struct-containing-strings
        let ptr = S.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_char;
        unsafe {
            desc.uri = ptr;
            return &desc as *const lv2::LV2Descriptor;
        }
    }
}

// fn instantiate<T>() -> *mut libc::c_void {
//     let ptr: *mut libc::c_void;
//     unsafe {
//         ptr = libc::malloc(mem::size_of::<T>() as libc::size_t) as *mut libc::c_void;
//         let plgptr = ptr as *mut T;
//     }
//     ptr
// }

// impl<'a> AmpNew<'a> {
//     fn new_ptr() -> *mut libc::c_void {
//         instantiate::<AmpNew>()
//     }
// }
```

Specific questions are contained in the code. The code uses functions and types [defined here](https://github.com/poidl/lv2/blob/master/src/core.rs).

Comment: This question would be much clearer if it concentrated on *one* use case and e.g. described a simple example of interfacing C and Rust possible to follow without specialized knowledge. It should probably also be split - one question is about references vs. pointers in `AmpNew`, and another about exposing Rust's generic functions to C.

Comment: I'm providing a specific use case in the example. Isn't the plugin as simple as it gets? The floats in the host-provided input buffer are multiplied by a constant. I agree that there are multiple questions, hence one is marked as the "main question".

Comment: I meant a use case that doesn't require external code and concepts to understand. For example, "take a C function with the following signature and the following ownership semantics; how would one go about wrapping it in Rust?"

Comment: OK fair enough I'll simplify it tomorrow. The drawback is it won't be complete any more. My previous questions all got edited by rust gurus anyways, let's see tomorrow.

Comment: Maybe it can be made complete (and self-contained) by providing the sample (and trivial) implementation of the C part? Ideally the question would include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), but that's not always feasible in practice.

Comment: OK I'll try to write SSCCE, what I meant by "complete" was "real life", i.e. a true LV2 plugin. But yeah I get it, for most people here that's little value if they're not into audio. I just thought, given it's so simple, I could get away with it.

Comment: Good point, but you can still include a github (or pastebin etc.) link for those who prefer to see the real-world use case.

Comment: Also, that GitHub user **might be wrong or incomplete**. There should be a `lv2-sys` (or something reasonable) that creates a [\*-sys package](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#-sys-packages). That crate **only** exposes the raw C API. Then, it's up to *other* crates (potentially more than one!) to expose an idiomatic Rust API. Maybe your crate should really just be the \*-sys package.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about *-sys packages. I think that was the hint I was looking for. So one packs all the close-to-C-like stuff in there, and provides a separate more high-level ("opinionated") package building on that? Sounds good.

Comment: All that opinionated and idiomatic API is closer to what @user4815162342 was getting at. If you phrase your question in terms of what the ownership and lifetimes of the underlying C code are, then we will be able to provide useful guidance on how to make a better API on top of it.

Comment: Good idea, I'll do that but first I think I'll improve the low level API. That will be more useful for people who know how to design the high level API.